# Webpack/Wordpress not loading all SCSS files of my React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, webpack, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm using WordPress 6.1.1 with Gutenberg 15.3.1 and default webpack.config.js.

I don't know why, but when I import more than one React component at the same level, their CSS doesn't get loaded.

edit.js

```
export default function Edit() {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps();

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <CentreWrapper data={centres}/>
            <CentreInformation data={centres}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

save.js:

```
export default function Save() {
    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <div id="centre-wrapper"></div>
            <div id="centre-information-wrapper"></div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Then, this code goes into a `client.js` file that is attached on the frontend using `viewScript` in `block.json`.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const centresWrapper = document.getElementById("centre-wrapper");
    const testWrapper = document.getElementById("centre-information-wrapper");

    if (centresWrapper) {
        render(<CentreWrapper data={centres} />, centresWrapper);
    }

    if (testWrapper) {
        render(<CentreInformation data={centres} />, testWrapper);
    }
});
```

Then, in my components I just import the SCSS files like this

```
import "./CentreInformation.scss";
const CentreInformation = ({ data }) => { }
```

It's even weirder because in the editor, the first component has its CSS loaded, but the second one doesn't. On the frontend, neither one of them has CSS.

In the Sources tab, the contents of the .scss files got changed to this:

```
// extracted by mini-css-extract-plugin
export {};
```

meaning that `MiniCSSExtractPlugin` has extracted the CSS but I don't know where it is.

Comment: What is the content of  `CentreInformation.scss`? I would suspect there might be a compile or syntax issue in the SCSS.

Comment: @S.Walsh no, it's not, files are fine. I found a workaround, to move all of my components' SCSS in a separate file and then just import this file into `style.scss` of the block with `@use "/src/styles/componentsStyles.scss";`. It's a really weird issue...

Comment: That's great you found a workaround. You can add your workaround as answer to your question as others may find it useful.